Create a percentage using a based field and a based item in SAS
Data sample
    Cohort  Years   Count   Status
2021    2   1   Graduated
2021    1   1   Active
2021    0   1   Active
2022    1   1   Graduated
2022    0   1   Active
2017    1   1   Active
2017    6   1   Graduated
2017    5   1   Graduated
2017    4   1   Active
2017    3   1   Active
2017    2   1   Active
2017    0   1   Active
2018    0   1   Active
2018    4   1   Graduated
2018    5   1   Graduated
2018    3   1   Active
2018    1   1   Active
2018    2   1   Active
2021    2   1   Graduated
2021    1   1   Active
2021    0   1   Active
2022    1   1   Withdraw
2022    0   1   Active
2022    1   1   Active
2022    0   1   Active
2019    3   1   Active
2019    2   1   Active
2019    1   1   Active
2019    0   1   Active
2019    4   1   Graduated
2021    2   1   Withdraw
2021    1   1   Active
2021    0   1   Active
2022    1   1   Withdraw
2022    0   1   Active
2017    6   1   Graduated
2017    5   1   Graduated
2017    4   1   Active
2017    3   1   Active
2017    2   1   Active
2017    1   1   Active
2017    0   1   Active
2023    0   1   Active
2018    5   1   Graduated
2018    4   1   Graduated
2018    3   1   Active
2018    2   1   Active
2018    1   1   Active
2018    0   1   Active
2022    1   1   Active
2022    0   1   Active
2021    1   1   Active
2021    0   1   Active
2021    2   1   Withdraw
2020    0   1   Active
2020    1   1   Active
2020    2   1   Active
2020    3   1   Graduated
2023    0   1   Active
2021    2   1   Withdraw
2021    1   1   Withdraw
2021    0   1   Active
2017    6   1   Graduated
2017    5   1   Graduated
2017    4   1   Active
2017    3   1   Active
2017    2   1   Active
2017    1   1   Active
2017    0   1   Active
2023    0   1   Active
2019    4   1   Graduated
2019    3   1   Active
2019    2   1   Active
2019    1   1   Active
2019    0   1   Active
2021    2   1   Active
2021    1   1   Active
2021    0   1   Active
2021    2   1   Withdraw
2021    1   1   Withdraw
2021    0   1   Active
2023    0   1   Active
2023    0   1   Active
2023    0   1   Active
2020    3   1   Graduated
2020    1   1   Active
2020    2   1   Active
2020    0   1   Active
2023    0   1   Active
2018    3   1   Active
2018    5   1   Graduated
2018    4   1   Graduated
2018    2   1   Active
2018    1   1   Active
2018    0   1   Active
2020    3   1   Graduated
2020    2   1   Graduated
2020    0   1   Active
2020    1   1   Active
2021    0   1   Active

The script I'm running to create a proc tabulate + percentage based on the "years = 0"
proc tabulate data=master;
where pmajr = 'AIT' and years<9; 
TITLE1 "table1 ";
class coh  years status;
table coh*(status all), (years) *(count pctn<years>="%") /printmiss misstext='0';  *norow nocol nopercent nocum;
run;

This gives me a row percentage, but WHAT I REALLY NEED IS to calculated the % based on the Years "0." For example, Year 0 (count=53) should be 100%. For the year 1 (count=40) percentage should be 75%. For year 2 (count=14) percentage should be 26%, and so on.
In other words, I need the percentage to be calculated by row but based on the column "years =0".
See the snip attached as an example: here
Thanks!

Huh?  Are you asking how to divide COUNT by the value of COUNT for the observation where YEARS=0?  What does all of the PROC TABULATE code have to do with that?  Note YEARS=0 only appears on observations that also have STATUS='Active'.  Is that the value you want to use for the denominator?

Hi Tom, I edited my post. The real data sample looks like the one updated above. Therefore, I need to create a proc tabulate to summarize that information. I need to know how many people are active and graduated per year, and I want to know the retention rate, which would be the percentage of the following years based on Year 0.

So just count first.  But the new data is different than the old data.  Most of your years will have 100%. Only 2020, 2021 show any attrition.

I copied a small dataset sample, as the original has 200K observations. I can't find the way to create that proc tabulate table and show the percentage I'm looking for. Do you have any insights for that? I would like to see it in the proc tabulate because I need to create many tables with different attributes, for example, gender, in-state, out-of-state, etc. So, ideally, I wouldn't want to create a COUNT FIRST for each variable that I need (gender, etc, etc).

You can use PROC FREQ or PROC SUMMARY to count.

To calculate a percentage just divide the numerator by the denominator. Looks like you want to use the value of COUNT when YEARS=0 as the denominator for each COH.
data have;
  input coh $ status $ years count;
datalines;
2012 Active 0 53
2012 Active 1 40
2012 Active 2 14
2012 Graduated 1 7
2012 Graduated 2 33
2013 Active 0 41
2013 Active 1 32
2013 Active 2 11
2013 Graduated 1 4
2013 Graduated 2 24
2014 Active 0 42
2014 Active 1 34
2014 Active 2 13
2014 Graduated 1 1
2014 Graduated 2 23
;

data want;
  merge have
        have(keep=coh years count rename=(years=_year count=year0)
             where=(_year=0))
  ;
  by coh  ;
  percent = divide(count,year0);
  drop _year ;
run;

Result
Obs    coh      status     years    count    year0    percent

  1    2012    Active        0        53       53     1.00000
  2    2012    Active        1        40       53     0.75472
  3    2012    Active        2        14       53     0.26415
  4    2012    Graduate      1         7       53     0.13208
  5    2012    Graduate      2        33       53     0.62264
  6    2013    Active        0        41       41     1.00000
  7    2013    Active        1        32       41     0.78049
  8    2013    Active        2        11       41     0.26829
  9    2013    Graduate      1         4       41     0.09756
 10    2013    Graduate      2        24       41     0.58537
 11    2014    Active        0        42       42     1.00000
 12    2014    Active        1        34       42     0.80952
 13    2014    Active        2        13       42     0.30952
 14    2014    Graduate      1         1       42     0.02381
 15    2014    Graduate      2        23       42     0.54762

If you only have the individual data then generate the COUNT values first
proc summary data=raw nway;
  class coh years status ;
  output out=HAVE(rename=(_freq_=COUNT));
run;

and then use the summary dataset as the input to the step that does the division.
